# How do I call my Javascript inside my other PHP file class

Tags: javascript, php

*i will try to create a language converter in using PHP* but I don't understand how to I call my js code in PHP class !!!

```
<?php 
     require_once __DIR__.'/src/Unicode2Bijoy.php';
?>



<script>

function myfunction(){
    var uni1_val = document.getElementById('uni1_val').value;
    console.log(uni1_val);

   var bijoy_result = <?php echo mirazmac\Unicode2Bijoy::convert($str) ?>;
   console.log(bijoy_result);
}
</script>
```

> how can i call this class and result show in my console

Comment: Can you share an error you get ?

Comment: Assuming it is a string, quote it `var bijoy_result = "<?php echo mirazmac\Unicode2Bijoy::convert($str) ?>";`

Comment: var bijoy_result = "<?php echo mirazmac\Unicode2Bijoy::convert($str) ?>"; error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1):

```
echo"<script>myfunction();</script>";
```

Comment: I wouldn't call JS inside PHP